# How does Master Yi's ultimate interact with Viktor's Gravity Field?

Tags: league-of-legends

Master Yi cannot be slowed while his Ultimate is active.

Viktor's Gravity Field spell causes all units in its AOE to receive a stacking slow debuff and will stun any hero that receives 3 stacks of this debuff.

If Master Yi is within the Gravity Field long enough that he *would have been stunned* if his ultimate wasn't preventing him from being slowed, will he still be stunned?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because Master Yi cannot be slowed, he does not receive the debuff or any stacks, preventing him from being stunned.

http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=2052671

Comment: Unfortunately, the comment from a Riot employee I linked was deleted.  I've left the link to the rest of the thread which still contains valuable information.

Answer (score 1):

Master Yi will have the "cannot be slowed" effect constantly popping up over him. You can try it out in game.